# if x is in dict.iterkey(), y is dict.value

Tags: python

I'm wondering how I can iterate through a multiple lists, match values to keys in a dict, then create a new lists equal to the values.

I'm new to stack and python, so help would be appreciated.

```
X1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
X2 = [3, 2, 2, 5, 1]
X3 = [2, 4,  3,  1,  5]

Y1 = []
Y2 = []

Z = {1:20, 2:19, 3:18, 4:17, 5:16}

def num_maker(num_list, new_list):
    for nums in num_list:
        if nums in Z.iterkeys():
            for newnums in new_list:
                new_list = Z.value(nums)

num_maker(X1, Y1)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Have you looked into `zip` ?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here. A [MCVE] needs some idea of inputs and outputs (both expected and observed); this isn't even syntactically valid, among many problems (`is in` isn't legal, `Z.value` isn't a thing, `Z.iterkeys` is only in the recently retired Python 2, nothing actually calls your function, etc.)

Comment: It's always good to give output, and why so much list elements in input, if you want to know the concept, you can keep 4-5 elements, it would be sufficient.

Comment: My expected output would be the opposite number, so if X1[0] = 1, Y1[0] = 20. I have not looked into zip.

Comment: What is your expected output? Add the expected output dictionary/list to the question, also you may wanna rephrase your question title... something like: Loop over multiple lists and create dictionary would be better.

Comment: @ChodBessie What you're looking for is something like `Y1 = [Z[x] for x in X1 if x in Z]` but for multiple lists at once?

Comment: @AbdurRehman Khan Expected output for Y1 would be [20,19,18,16,17], based on X1. I'm also not trying to create a new dict, but a new list.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson This answers my question for the most part, thank you. Sorry for the mass confusion everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're interested in learning how to do this *without* the list comprehension provided by @Joachim Isaksson

Here's what you need to do:

```
# Your number list
X1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]

# Your dictionary with keys from the number list
Z = {1:20, 2:19, 3:18, 4:17, 5:16}

# Expected output list should be: [20,19,18,16,17] based on X1

def num_maker(num_list, dictionary_of_num_list):

    # Initialize empty list
    list_to_return = []
    # Loop over your num_list
    for number in num_list:
        # Access the dictionary using the list's current element as the key and then append it to a new list which you can return
        list_to_return.append(dictionary_of_num_list.get(number))

    return list_to_return

print(num_maker(X1, Z))
```

Output:

```
[20, 19, 18, 16, 17]
```

You want Y1 as the output list right so for that you would do:

```
Y1 = num_maker(X1, Z)
```

Hope this helps. Run this using python 3, NOT python 2.

Comment: Just to make sure it doesn't ends abruptly: `list_to_return.append(dictionary_of_num_list.get(number))`

Comment: This answer doesn't consider the case where "number" from num_list won't be present in the dictionary.

Comment: @Ashwani It does. If number won't be present in the dictionary then "None" will be appended to the list. That's how dictionary.get("key") works as opposed to dictionary["key"]. Unless, he doesn't want to append anything in that case, then yeah the code would require an additional if statement.

Comment: Yes, but in most cases, we don't want "None" in our result.

Answer (score 0):

> this is the easy to achieve that

```
X1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
X2 = [3, 2, 2, 5, 1]
X3 = [2, 4,  3,  1,  5]

Y1 = []
Y2 = []

Z = {1:20, 2:19, 3:18, 4:17, 5:16}

def num_maker(num_list, new_list):
        new_list=[Z[nums] for nums in num_list ]
        return new_list
print(num_maker(X1, Y1))
```